# How to retain all the attributes in html of ckeditor 5 in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ckeditor5

I need to retrive html along with all the attributes used in it.

in html component i have declared like below.

```
<ckeditor [editor]="Editor" [(ngModel)]="newDatatable" ></ckeditor>
```

in ts component i have mentioned simple table string as below

```
this.newDatatable = 
`<table><tr><td class='baseclass'>Sr</td><td>name</td><td>address</td>
<tr><td class='baseclass'>1</td><td>abc</td><td>abd</td>
</tr></table>`;
```

but if i edit something in ckeditor i got the following html without the attributes

```
`<table><tr><td>Sr</td><td>name</td><td>address</td>
<tr><td>1</td><td>abc</td><td>abd</td>
</tr></table>`;
```

so i need the all the attributes as it is.